# Dxhtml Gantt chart in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gantt-chart

When I try to add a subtask A after a subtask B which has add button when I hit the button the subtask A is getting added inside subtask B which makes subtask B as a parent of subtask A but I need subtask A to get added after subtask B and both should have same parent let us consider Task C as parent task

[Output which is required where TaskC gets added after TaskB for both the tasks Parent is TaskA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYD3g.png)
[output which I have got where TaskC getting added under TaskB whose parent is TaskA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYQRR.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just need a solution for how to add a new task after another task in Gantt chart without making the task above as the parent of the new task